# sending multiple value through ajax to another page

Tags: ajax

```
  function rates()
        {
       var a=document.getElementById("measure_unit").value; 

b=document.getElementById("weight_slot").value;



 if (a=="")
        {
      document.getElementById("credit7").innerHTML="";

      return;
}


          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
         else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
//document.getElementById("ajax_details2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("credit7").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
     }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/rate_details.php?q="+a,true);

    xmlhttp.send();     


 }
```

this is the ajax that i have applied here i am sending the value a to another php page..php code as follows.

```
            <?php
          include 'dbcon.php';
         $q = $_GET['q'];
```

?>

Volumetric Weight : " onclick="rates()"/>

now above i am passing only one variable that is a to another page but i also want to send the value of b and want to print it in the div that i have taken with the value of that div...by concatenating ...so how to send two values together and printing them together....help guyz

Answer (score 0):

In your request:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/rate_details.php?q=" + a + "&q2=" + b,true);
```

And in PHP:

```
$b = $_GET['q2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using parametes as Data Transfer so why not at the b in the parametes like:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/rate_details.php?q="+a+**"&valb="+b**
```

The & is a connector for Multiple Parameters in URLs

And in PHP you go access them with:

```
 $q = $_GET['q'];
**$valb = $_GET['valb'];**
```

Well I can't test this atm, but i think this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is how u can send multiple parametrs in AJAX
xreq.open("post", "Xyz?&variable=" + projectName + "&whichSelect="+ id);